# On Keydown Event It should play matching audio

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In this code, when keyboard event <kbd>A</kbd> was pressed its keycode 65 should match the audio tag's attribute data-key = "65" and play.
But when I `querySelector` it returning me null in console log.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drumkit</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio data-key="65" src="audio/clap.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="83" src="audio/hihat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="68" src="audio/kick.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="70" src="audio/openhat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="71" src="audio/boom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="72" src="audio/ride.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="74" src="audio/snare.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="75" src="audio/tom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="76" src="audio/tink.wav"></audio>
      
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
            const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
           
            
            console.log(audio);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the only problematic key 65, or none of them works?

Comment: @vahdet no "A" is just an example all of them returning null

Comment: @MunafHajir If my answer solved your problem then accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @CodeF0x you need to use ES6 template string. Hence you need to use backticks or backquote **`** instead of single quotes **'** which can be found on the key below `esc` key

However, the string will not properly interpolate in the function call arguments in your case the `querySelector()` function.

Hence store your template string output in a variable and pass this variable in the function call and this will solve your problem.

**Just Use Like This**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drumkit</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio data-key="65" src="audio/clap.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="83" src="audio/hihat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="68" src="audio/kick.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="70" src="audio/openhat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="71" src="audio/boom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="72" src="audio/ride.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="74" src="audio/snare.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="75" src="audio/tom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="76" src="audio/tink.wav"></audio>

        <script>
            window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
            var selector = `audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`;
            const audio = document.querySelector(selector);

            console.log(audio);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:** As you wanted

[image]

Please refer [Getting Literal With ES6 Template Strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) for more help

Answer (score 2):

For using ES6 a Template-String, you need to use ` instead of '.

You may also want read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) documentation.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drumkit</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio data-key="65" src="audio/clap.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="83" src="audio/hihat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="68" src="audio/kick.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="70" src="audio/openhat.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="71" src="audio/boom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="72" src="audio/ride.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="74" src="audio/snare.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="75" src="audio/tom.wav"></audio>
        <audio data-key="76" src="audio/tink.wav"></audio>
      
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
            const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
           
            
            console.log(audio);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an alternative you can use `const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');`